# Set MapContainer cameraPosition to show all points

Tags: codenameone

I have an array latlong values which I want to display on the map. The challenge is I want a dynamic cameraPosition to show all the points at once, regardless of the distance between them.

I already tried the MapContainer.setCameraPosition(lat,long) to the last values from the Array. y question now is what is the right zoom level to use or is there another way this can be achieved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `fitBounds` which accepts a bounding box containing the top left coordinate and the bottom right coordinate. E.g.

```
mapc.fitBounds(new BoundingBox(southWestCoord, northEastCoord));
```

You can also use

```
mapc.fitBounds(BoundingBox.create(arrayOfCoords));
```